# What is a good tool to scan a FTP directory and show disk usage visually ala KDirStat/WinDirStat?

Tags: ftp

Is there a tool that can scan an FTP directory and build a visual representation of disk usage? I'm running on Windows so that platform is my preference for this tool, but a *NIX tool would also be useful. I'm thinking along the lines of WinDirStat, KDirStat and TreeSize. At first I thought WinDirStat might be able to scan an FTP directory, but it was not so. FOSS is a plus, but not a requirement (I'm not against paying for good software).

I'd like to also have a simple report on how many of what types of files are present, largest files, etc. Much like the simple file type reporting in *DirStat.

Comment: This question was closed because shopping recommendations are outside of the scope of Server Fault. [Please ensure you are familiar with the FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq#questions). ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done this by using a third party utility to map an FTP site to a drive letter and then using my directory reporting tool to scan the mapped drive (I use FolderSizes 4). Here are two that I've used:

http://www.killprog.com/fdrve.html

http://www.divshare.com/download/2012951-371

Note: This is a Windows solution.

Comment: You know, I was wondering if I could map an FTP address to a drive letter but wimped out and didn't Google it. =) Great idea! Let's see if anyone can recommend a purely FTP based tool to do this before I endow a green check mark.

Comment: I did search for and attempt a strictly FTP method of doing it but had no luck.

Comment: Do you mind editing your answer to explicitly say this is a Windows solution? Now we have two similar solutions: mine for Linux, yours for Windows. Saying that explicitly might help future readers.

Comment: @Denilson I stated "I'm running on Windows so that platform is my preference for this tool, but a *NIX tool would also be useful." So... shouldn't that sum things up nicely?

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the [brilliant joeqwerty idea](https://serverfault.com/questions/136373/what-is-a-good-tool-to-scan-a-ftp-directory-and-show-disk-usage-visually-ala-kdir/136401#136401), you can use **[curlftpfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) on Linux**. It uses [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) to mount a remote FTP directory into a local directory.

Then, you can just use a one-liner shell command...

```
du -skc * | sort -n
```

Or use [ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) on the terminal. Or use graphical programs like [xdiskusage](http://xdiskusage.sourceforge.net/) or [filelight](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/filelight?content=99561) or [baobab](http://www.gnome.org/projects/baobab/).

If you have ssh access to the server, maybe installing [philesight](http://zevv.nl/play/code/philesight/) might be a nice idea (or using [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) instead of curlftpfs).

Comment: Great, I'll keep that in my bag of tricks. I hope you get a few extra +1's for all of your links. =) Thanks!